# Flattening a list that contains lists of tuples, letters and integers

Tags: python, list, recursion, tuples

I need to flatten a list recursively:

Before the list looks like:

```
L=[1,[2,[‘a’,(3,’b’)]],(5,6),([11,22])]
```

After:

```
Lflat=[1,2,’a’,(3,’b’),(5,6),([11,22])]
```

I've come across an issue with my code (lst1 is an empty lst1)

```
def list_flatten(lst,lst1):
    for item in lst:
        if type(item) == tuple:
            print(item)
            lst1.append(item)
        elif type(item) == list:
            list_flatten(item,lst1)
        else:
            lst1.append(item)
    return lst1
```

This returns the following:

OUTPUT : `[1, 2, 'a', (3, 'b'), (5, 6), 11, 22]`

Which lead me to find out that ([]) is considered a list, not a tuple.

Now my questions are as following:

1. Say I were to define lst1=[] inside the main program. How do I make
   it so the recursion doesn't empty the list out every iteration?
2. Why is ([]) considered a list?

Comment: `([])` is a list because a [tuple consists of a number of values separated by commas](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), and there are no commas here. In this case, the parentheses are just forcing the evaluation of what's *inside* the parentheses, which is a list.

Comment: `([],)` is a tuple.  Don't worry, this confuses everyone.

Comment: @DavidZemens True, but the function mutates `lst1`, so it really doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: I don't understand your question #1. The recursion _doesn't_ "empty the list out every iteration", it passes `lst1` to the recursive call with its contents intact.

Comment: @PM2Ring If I were to add lst1= [] inside of the fucntion instead of calling a list from outside of the function, it would keep trample over the list every recursion run

Answer (score 2):

Your `list_flatten` function mutates the `lst1` argument, so you don't really need to return anything. You can call it like this:

```
L = [1,[2,['a',(3,'b')]],(5,6),([11,22])] 

def list_flatten(lst, lst1):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            list_flatten(item, lst1)
        else:
            lst1.append(item)

Lflat = []
list_flatten(L, Lflat)
print(Lflat)
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 'a', (3, 'b'), (5, 6), 11, 22]
```

It's recommended to use `isinstance` rather than `type` because that makes the code more versatile: it will also work with objects derived from `list`.

We can re-write the function so that you don't need to pass in `lst1`:

```
def list_flatten(lst, lst1=None):
    if lst1 is None:
        lst1 = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            list_flatten(item, lst1)
        else:
            lst1.append(item)
    return lst1

Lflat = list_flatten(L)
print(Lflat)
```

We give `lst1` a default value of `None` and on the top level of the recursion we re-bind the name `lst1` to an empty list to collect the results.

We can't give `lst1` a default value of `[]`. That's because default args are created when the function is compiled, not when the function is called, and if we gave `lst1` a default value of `[]` that same list would get used on every call. It would look like it does what we want the first time we used `list_flatten`, but it would not behave as desired on subsequent calls. Here's a short demo.

```
L = [1,[2,['a',(3,'b')]],(5,6),([11,22])] 

def list_flatten(lst, lst1=[]):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            list_flatten(item, lst1)
        else:
            lst1.append(item)
    return lst1

Lflat = list_flatten(L)
print(Lflat)
Lflat = list_flatten(L)
print(Lflat)
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 'a', (3, 'b'), (5, 6), 11, 22]
[1, 2, 'a', (3, 'b'), (5, 6), 11, 22, 1, 2, 'a', (3, 'b'), (5, 6), 11, 22]
```

As you can see, `lst1` has retained its contents from the first call. For more info on this important topic, please see [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). There are times when this behviour is desirable, but in such cases it's wise to add a comment to your code that you're intentionally using a mutable default argument.

---

Yet another way is to make `list_flatten` into a generator, and collect its output into a list:

```
def list_flatten(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            yield from list_flatten(item)
        else:
            yield item

Lflat = list(list_flatten(L))
print(Lflat)
```

In recent versions of Python you can replace `list(list_flatten(L))` with `[*list_flatten(L)]`.

Python 2 doesn't have `yield from`, but you can replace that line with:

```
for u in list_flatten(item):
    yield u
```

If you don't actually need the list you can call the generator like this:

```
for u in list_flatten(L):
    print(u)
```

**output**

```
1
2
a
(3, 'b')
(5, 6)
11
22
```

Answer (score 2):

You can note that what you need is:

- if the list is empty, return it unchanged
- if it has one single element and that element is not a list, return the list unchanged
- else flatten first element, flatten the end of the list and concatenate the two sublists

In Python code, it leads to:

```
def flatten(L):
    if len(L) == 0: return L
    elif len(L) == 1 and not isinstance(L[0], list): return L
    else:
        return (flatten(L[0] if isinstance(L[0], list)
                else [L[0]]) + flatten(L[1:]))
```

it gives as expected:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 'a', (3, 'b'), (5, 6), ([11, 22],)]
>>> flatten(L)
[1, 2, 'a', (3, 'b'), (5, 6), ([11, 22],)]
```