# Combining two arguments of a function

Tags: python, list, function

So I started learning python in my free time, because of covid.
Yesterday I tried creating a function that converts two arguments into one list and combines them.
For example I created a function: sumup((1,2,3),(4,5,6)) that returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. This was fairly easy to do.

```
def sumup(arg1, arg2):
    combine_1 = list(arg1 + arg2)

    return combine_1
```

But now im trying to figure out how I can combine tuples and lists. So sumup((1,2,3), [565]) should return [1,2,3,565].

I'd be glad if someone could give me some hints.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808623/flattening-a-list-that-contains-lists-of-tuples-letters-and-integers answer your question?

Comment: Do `combine_1 = list(arg1) + list(arg2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want to accomplish, but at a glance, I would suggest that you convert your tuple to a list in order to concatenate both lists. Here is an illustration:

```
def merge_tuple_and_list(tuple, mlist):
    return np.concatenate([list(tuple), mlist])

print(merge_tuple_and_list((1,2,3), [565]))
print(type(merge_tuple_and_list((1,2,3), [565])))
```

Output:

```
array([  1,   2,   3, 565])
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use NumPy for this basic task.